# Access remote system files on port 445, given ip address using java

Tags: java, sockets, port, .net

I am developing a java application which scans all the systems over the local area network, and gives a list of systems having some files shared, thus making port 445 open. I can check whether port 445 is open or not, but how can I get the list of files or directories shared by the target system, given that I know the ip address of the target system. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

This program is similar to another program 'netscan' (windows).

Comment: That's [SMB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233(v=vs.85).aspx). Take a look at an SMB/CIFS client library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) is a library to access SMB shares directly from Java. Read more detailed documentation [here](http://blog.bensmann.com/adding-jcifs-to-javaiofile-for-easy-access-to)